# qt share variables between slots

Tags: qt, qstring

Im having trouble figuring out how to use variables across slots. I have read the signals and slots page a few times over and haven't been able to figure out exactly how to use the connect function. I'm trying to have one button to select the directory, and then have it sent over to the other slot for when I hit print, so it can use that directory. Thanks for the help.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QApplication app(int argc, char** argv());
int n = 107;

for (int q = 1; q <= n; q++)
{
        QString fileName =(folderName + "/batch_%1.jpg").arg(q);
        // QPrinter printer;
        //QPrintDialog *dlg = new QPrintDialog(&printer,0);
        //if(dlg->exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
        printer.setResolution(300);
        printer.setCopyCount(1);
        printer.setDoubleSidedPrinting(false);
        printer.setDuplex(QPrinter::DuplexNone);
        printer.setColorMode(QPrinter::Color);
        printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::Letter);
        printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::Letter);
        printer.setPaperSource(QPrinter::Auto);
        printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
        printer.setPageMargins(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, QPrinter::Inch);
        QString outputFileName = QStringLiteral("/Users/alexdotzler/Desktop/testing/test%1.pdf").arg(q);
        printer.setOutputFileName(outputFileName);
                printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
                QImage img(fileName);
                QPainter painter(&printer);
                painter.drawImage(QPoint(0,0),img);
                painter.end();
        }

        //delete dlg;

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()

{

QString folderName = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(0, ("Select file"), QDir::currentPath());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, remember about [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is not only about example, but also about **minimal**. In this case, your printing code is not nessessary.

Following your question, **slot** is just a function of class. And in your case, you can jist create printing function, that will be called from both pushButton 1 and 2.

Also, don't be await of real magic from sig/slots. It looks like, but not. Connect slot to signal is just virtual call to function B when function A called.

Then let's go a bit deeply into the world of signals and slots.

1. You can connect  (slots or signals) to signals . No other way.
2. Basically, signals and slots used to pass data between different objects or to inform them about something.

```
// foo.h
    class First {
...
signals:
    void newData(QVariant val);
};

// bar.h
    class Another {...
public slots:
    void getNewData(QVariant val);
};

// main.cpp
Another another1;
First first1;
QObject::connect(first1, &First::newData, another1, &Another::getNewData);
```

3. You can also create something can be called "Connections tree", when signal [Another::sig1] connected to [Third::sig2], which connected to signal [Fourth::sig3] and slot [Fifth::slot1], and so on. I'm not sure someone really need it, but be free to play with.
4. AFAIK, the only reason to use signal/slot connection inside single class, is when you need to pass some data to GUI thread from another thread running in GUI. Please, don't do that in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

Make `folderName` a member of your `MainWindow` class so it will be accessible by your pushButton clicked slots. Then you can read/write it as necessary from those slots.